# После связывания сборок появляется ошибка namespace`ов

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Всем привет! Вопрос по сборкам.
Все скрипты и cборка нахоядтся по пути `Assets/Scripts`. Скрипты `IronSource` (которые не видит) находятся по пути `Assets/IronSource/Scripts`.

По этому пути нету никакой сборки, чтобы ее присоединить. Почему-то мои скрипты по дефолту не видят `IronSource` скрипты.

Попробовал сделать сборку `ІronSource` и дать ссыслку на нее в сборку `Scripts`, а теперь вылазит ошибка:

> The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'IronSource' after adding assembly.

Класс не дублируется. Как я могу могу решить проблему?

До того, как создал сборки:

[image: До того как создал сборки]

Сборка `Scripts` до создания и привязки `IronSource`:

[image: Сборка Scripts до создания и привязки IronSource]

Сборка `IronSource`:

[image: Сборка IronSource]

Сборка `Scripts` после присоединения `IronSource`:

[image: Сборка Scripts после присоединения IronSource]

Ошибка неймспейсов, которая вылезла после привязки сборок:

[image: Ошибка неймспейсов которая вылезла после привязки сборок]